# Can't print cd cover to canon pixma ip4800

Tags: printing, canon

the printer happily outputs test page accurately but I cannot get disk print to function at all. Any assistance would be much appreciated. Current driver version is Canon IP4800 Canon iP4800 series Ver.3.40